# Trailrenderer can only be black

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to have a trail renderer on an empty gameobject, it does get on it, but it can only emit the trail with a block color. When there's no texture attached the trail gets pink, if I do attach any material in any color it becomes black.

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: its possible that you have no lights in your scene - try assigning an unlit material